# Birth Record for Son of Scottish Surgeon Attached to Canadian Regiment During US Occupation

Tags: united-states, military-records, birth-records, canada, united-kingdom

James Davidson, Surgeon, born in Scotland, attached to Royal Canadian Emigrant regiment 1775-1779, and then attached to the 84th regiment from 1781-1785.

Official posting (documented) is to Quebec City, however, regiment campaigned in US.  Son's census records (as well as other documents) indicate birth in Bennington, Vermont in the 1780-1790 time period.

Mother's name assumed to be Jane Richardson, James' first wife.

Where would I locate a birth record for the son, Benjamin Davidson, who served as a Serjeant in the Glengarry Fencibles from 1812-1815 and later located to Brighton, Northumberland, Ontario?

I have reviewed records of Chaplains Returns and Quartermaster Returns at the BNA and on FindMyPast, but am unable to locate any birth record.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! By 'Quartermaster Returns' do you mean the records titled [British Nationals Armed Forces Births 1761-2005](http://search.findmypast.com/search-world-Records/british-nationals-armed-forces-births-1761-2005)?  [Vermont Vital Records](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Vermont_Vital_Records) begin about 1760 at the town level so you'd have to search at the local level (no statewide registration at that time).

Comment: I have reviewed both of those locations as well as the un-indexed Bennington, VT records on FamilySearch.  The Quartermaster Returns are normally paymaster records but sometimes included family information; unfortunately, no info there.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ontariogenealogy.com/easternontariobaptisms.html
Central Upper Canada database -Upper Canada East

Davidson-David 1835

```
    -James 1837

    -Samuel 1797

    -Sophy  1804

    -William 1841
```

You could use this as a starting point. People with the same family name in the same relative area are usually related. These are probably descendants of either James or Benjamin. By back tracking by researching records there is bound to be connection.